# Is there anything in c similar to Reflection API and annotations are in java.?

Tags: java, c, jsp, webserver, httpserver

Recently, I've implemented an HTTP Server in c language. it serves static resources very well when requesting client request it to serve. Now I want it to serve dynamic resources like jsp in java (tomcat), means some piece of code could execute at server side and response should be sent. I've done this kind of things in java using reflection, annotations and using other core libraries but I've never done this in c before.

Can someone guide me to do this in c.Thanks in advance.

Comment: There isn't anything similar to either of those things in C.

Answer (score 0):

While there are no equivalent facilities similar to Reflection API or Annotation in C, it is still possible to implement what you require, but it will need you to do some heavy lifting.

Mainly what I am getting is that you want to:

1. Figure out what the type of the resource is
2. Depending on the type, you want to execute it with some script and send its output.

For part 1 you could base it on the extension of the resource. You could use system MIME types, or you could create your own mapping like this:

```
struct Mapping {
   char *extension;
   char *command;
};

struct Mapping mapping[] = {
                            {"jsp", "<command to run jsp>"},
                            {"sh", "/bin/bash %1"}
};
```

For part 2, when your server receives a request, it needs to extract the extension of the resource, and check in the mapping to see which entry matches the extension, obtain the `command` field and execute the command (after substituting arguments if any) using `system()` call.

Note that as an assignment this is a great way to learn a lot of things, but if you put this in production, it will be a huge security hole!